# Evaluation of $\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the given integral:

> $$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}}dx$$

After using $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx= \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x)dx$, we get $\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{\sin(x)+\cos(x)} dx$ but I am not able to solve this integral. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: How did you reach from first integral to second one?Is it correct? is it should be $\int _{ \pi /6 }^{ \pi /3 } \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+\cot { \left( x \right)  }  }  } dx$ or i'm wrong

Comment: @mathGeek. Just wondering, is this a book problem?

Answer (score 8):

Hint:  Let $u=\sqrt{1+\tan x}$, so $du=\frac{\sec^2x}{2\sqrt{1+\tan x}}dx\;$.  Then

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan x}}dx=2\int\frac{1}{1+\tan^2x}\frac{\sec^2 x}{2\sqrt{1+\tan x}}dx=2\int\frac{1}{1+(u^2-1)^2}du=2\int\frac{1}{u^4-2u^2+2}du$.

Next use partial fractions:

---

Since $u^4-2u^2+2=[(u^2)^2+2\sqrt{2}u^2+(\sqrt{2})^2]-(2+2\sqrt{2})u^2=(u^2+\sqrt{2})^2-\left(\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u\right)^2$

$\hspace{1.32 in}=\left(u^2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(u^2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}\right)$,

$\hspace{.4 in}\displaystyle\frac{1}{u^4-2u^2+2}=\frac{Au+B}{u^2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Cu+D}{u^2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}}$ so

$\hspace{.3 in}1=(Au+B)\left(u^2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}\right)+(Cu+D)\left(u^2-\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}\right)$.

1) $u=0\;$ gives $B+D=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

2) the $u^3$ coefficient gives $0=A+C$

3) the $u$ coefficient gives $0=\sqrt{2}(A+C)+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}(B-D)$, so $\color{blue}{B=D=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}}$

4) the $u^2$ coefficient gives $0=\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}(A-C)+(B+D)=\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}(A-C)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$,

so $A-C=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{2}$ and $\color{blue}{A=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{4}}$ and $\color{blue}{C=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{4}}$.

(Now integrate each term.)

Comment: I am just wondering, how would you do partial fractions? It's not factorable over the reals. The only option would be that it is factorable into two prime quadratic polynomials, but I can't find those either...Wolfram gives me this: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2Fsqrt%7B1%2Btanx%7D&random=false

Comment: @imranfat  I will try to edit my answer, to show how the partial fractions expansion can be obtained.  (I stopped where I did because I saw that the numbers didn't turn out very nice.)

Comment: It looks good by looking horrible:) On top of that, it is a definite integral too, so once the anti derivative is established, either back substitution or tagging the limits along....

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$, and you get an Elliptic Integral of Second Kind. This part has been posted here at MSE.